# SQL query performance is slow after table reindex but fast after EXEC sp_updatestats

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, indexing, statistics

I had a problem where my queries were taking an excessively long time to run.
After investigation i found the tables were not being maintained. Reindexing hadnt been run in a long time and index fragmentation was over 90% on all relevant tables.

So i reindexed the tables but my query was still taking a very long time.

I then manually ran `EXEC sp_updatestats`
After this my query ran very fast.

I was under the impression that a Reindex should automatically compute the statistics on the full table and manually running the update stats would only make things worse as it updates the stats based on a sample of data rather than the whole table.

Any ideas?

Comment: As far as I'm aware running update statistics can cause your query to recompile but it may recompile to a better (more efficient) plan. I was under the impression that rebuilding indexes caused them to have statistics on a sample and updating statistics would compute them on the full table. I could be wrong though.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the distribution of data in the columns. Look up update statistics - you'll find you can specify the selectivity you want to use when running it. The default sampling level depends on the size of the data.

Most people run update stats after index work on maintenance plans.